# Is there a way to add html markup to target each column individually in Chartjs/Canvasjs?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, canvasjs

I'm hoping I can add markup to each dataset individually so that I can change the colors with css.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var data = {
        labels: ["(1)","(2)","(3)","(4)","(5)"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Food Chart",
                fillColor: "#000066",
                strokeColor: "transparent",
                pointColor: "red",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: calcChart(),
            }
        ]
    }
    var options = {
        scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
        barValueSpacing : 5,
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,
        barValueSpacing : 25
    }
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Chart.js and Canvasjs both use the canvas element to draw the charts you can't interact with the elements using CSS.

If you want to use custom CSS to the chart elements you will need to use a SVG library like highcharts.

Comment: Do you know of a way of setting a color pallet before hand, then just calling it in? I tired using an array but couldn't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It seems like you are using V1 of chart.js from the syntax I am seeing. That version does not support arrays for colors. Your best bet is to upgrade to the latest version 3.7.1, Then you can use arrays for colors or functions.